# What happens if I use a regular diode instead of a zener?

Tags: diodes, zener

Does the diode catastrophically fail? Does it unreliably breakdown? Does it stop conducting? What happens if I use a regular diode as a Zener diode?

Comment: I think you need to show an example on such a circuit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an ordinary Si diode the breakdown voltage will be unpredictable (it should be higher than the rated voltage, but how much higher is not controlled) but it should not be damaged if the current is sufficiently limited. It will be avalanche breakdown rather than Zener breakdown (similar to 'Zener' diodes of more than 5-10V).

That's how breakdown voltage is measured non-destructively, for example in a curve tracer. For example, [this](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf) 1N4148 is measured at 100uA.

Long term reliability under such conditions is  not guaranteed, and the 'knee' may not be as sharp as a diode optimized for the application so you probably would not want to do this as part of a real product. Real higher-voltage (up into the hundreds of volts) Zener diodes are inexpensive and come fully characterized.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of the circuit.

A standard diode does not behave like a zener so if the rest of the circuit depends on the operation of the zener diode, then a normal diode can't be used.

For example If the zener is used for voltage regulation or limiting, a standard diode will not behave like a zener and won't regulate or limit the voltage, so the rest of the circuit gets overvoltage and may be damaged.

Comment: I think the OP is asking, _in what way_ does a "regular" diode not behave like a zener? They both have a _reverse breakdown voltage,_ but while zener normally would be operated near that voltage, a regular diode normally would not. OP is asking why not? What would happen if you allowed a "regular" diode to break down?